# Limits Continuous function proof

Tags: calculus

Prove that $() = ^{3}$ is continuous at $ = −2$.

I'm trying to understand how to prove this using the epsilon delta method. If someone could please guide me, that would be great!

This was my method: [image]

Comment: you should give it a try and include your attempt.

Comment: I did include my attempt

Answer (score 3):

You could try it like this

$|x|-|c|\leq|x-c|<\delta=1\Rightarrow |x|<1+|c|$

So, $|x^2+cx+c|\leq 1+|c|^2+2|c|+(1+|c|)|c|+|c|=1+2|c|^2+4|c|$

and now take $\delta=min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|c|^2+4|c|}\}$

P.S.- Though the simplest way would be to first prove that the product of continuous functions is continuous(standard proof (by $\epsilon\ - \delta$) in every analysis textbook) and then express $x^3=x\times x\times x$ where continuity of x is very easy to show.

Here's the standard proof(I have skipped some of the simpler steps)- We need to show $fg$ is cont. where $f$ and $g$ are cont., consider 
$$|f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(c)|=|f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(c)+f(x)g(c)-f(c)g(c)|\leq |f(x)||g(x)-g(c)|+|g(c)||f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon\ if\ |x-c|<\delta$$ 
s.t. $\delta=min\{\delta_{f_1},\delta_{f_2},\delta_g\},$ 
where $\delta_{f_1}$ was chosen s.t. $|f(x)-f(c)|<1\Rightarrow |f(x)|<1+|f(c)|$, $\delta_{f_2}$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2g(c)}$ 
and $\delta_{g}$ s.t. $|g(x)-g(c)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|f(c)|)}$

Comment: hmm do you mind showing me the standard proof. Im not sure i follow

Comment: I have included it in the edit